# How should I use units? -> When should I write "Kraft in N", "Kraft in Newton" and "Kraft [N]" in running text and axis descriptions?

Tags: rule-of-thumb

For papers, theses and other academic kinds of publications, the regular method of writing axis labels/descriptions is

> Kraft [N]

So regarding the aspect of figures where data is displayed somehow, I just included that for the sake of completeness. Note: there is of course also the method in publishing to include a lengthy description in the figure itself, e.g. [The Economist uses this practice](http://www.economist.com/news/china/21621849-censors-delete-news-hong-kongs-protests-not-quite-fast-enough-hk-backspace-backspace).

How should should I describe the axis label from above in running text though? What are good regularities?

Comment: How is that a question about the German language?

Comment: @CarstenSchultz Admittedly this is not about the language in the strict sense.

Comment: @CarstenSchultz Would you happen to a suggestion where this could/should have been posted?

Comment: [Academia.se] might be a better fit... they are English only but IMO stuff like that is mostly language-agnostic

Comment: @Vogel612 Academia is a bad fit. This is not a question about academia but a question about how to write units in German. Since that may well be different to how units are written in English, it seems like it's on-topic, here.

Comment: @DavidRicherby Maybe [Physics](http://physics.stackexchange.com/) might be a better fit?

Comment: @DavidRicherby that's why I used *"might"* ;) additionally this is especially about units in context of academic papers! not about writing units in ... wherever...

Comment: @CarstenSchultz: It's a question about typical use of a certain category of words in the German language.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, never write the unit symbol (here: N for Newton) within square brackets!
This terrible, widespread error is a clear violation of all applicable international standards (ISO, DIN etc.).

> <s>Kraft *F* [N]</s>
>   <s>Kraft [N]</s>
>   <s>*F* [N]</s>

You should write

> Kraft *F* in N

If it is clear from the context what the quantity symbol *F* is, you may label the columns of a table or the axes of a graph with

> *F* in N

or

> *F*/N

Usually, it is not necessary to mention the unit symbol within the body text when you are referring to a figure or table:

> Der Verlauf der Kraft *F* in Abhängigkeit vom Druck *p* ist in Abbildung 1 dargestellt.

Comment: Oh wow,... I am kidn of glad to read this. Because so far I used the method "*F* in N".  I made this thread to inquire ... to reassure if I had to, going forward, convert what I had written down until now. Well, for giving the check mark, could you please source what you wrote? :)

Comment: I'm actually perusing through the [NIST's document on this right now](http://www.nist.gov/pml/pubs/sp811/index.cfm) but so far I have only spotted the method *F* / N (<- inserted spaces because the *F* wouldn't be italic otherwise). Hm...

Comment: Not a legal norm, but according to [this pdf](http://www.ieap.uni-kiel.de/surface/ag-berndt/lehre/aprakt/allg/einheiten.pdf) the university of Kiel also uses the quotient notation: "Auch die Beschriftung von Tabellenköpfen und Koordinatenachsen erfolgt im Sinne von
zugeschnittenen Größengleichungen. Der an den entsprechenden Stellen stehende Quotient aus
physikalischer Größe und Einheit ist der Zahlenwert der betreffenden Größe."

Comment: @Hulk Thank you. I did only see your comment because Carsten wrote something above, under the op. You see if you are dressing  another commentator, you need to use the @-sign. The poster of the reply always gets notified AFAIK.

Comment: "This terrible, widespread error" - if it's so widespread, maybe it's not an "error", but rather a *convention* - especially in situations where it's not clear from the conference whether the unit or the quantity symbol is meant, and where italic is not reliably feasible (e.g. in hand-written text).